# Вызов callback для reCaptcha из внешнего файла

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

Добрый день

Проблема заключается в том, что если скрипт с функцией callback для reCaptcha в том же html где эта reCaptcha вставлена, то callback срабатывает, а при выносе скрипта во внешний файл - нет (остальные функции скрипта выполняются как надо)

```
#feedback.html.haml
...
.row
   = recaptcha_tags :callback => "re_check"

...

#script.js
$(function(){
...
function re_check(){
 if ((name_f.value == "")|| (phone_f.value == "")){
  show_error();
 }
  validate();
 }
...
})
```

Как исправить?

---

**Добавлено 1 сентября**

Проблема оказалась не в том, что скрипт во внешнем файле, а в том, что он обернут в $(function(){    }). Еще не выясняла как исправить

Comment: Ну значит вопрос в том, как вы подключаете этот внешний файл. Попробуйте в callback вставить такую функцию **function(){ alert(re_check); }** и определить её в этом же файле.

Comment: @vihtor, = recaptcha_tags :callback => "function(){ alert(re_check); }", так? Если так, то не помогло

Comment: я не силен в haml, но нужно что бы получилось так **<recaptcha_tags callback="alert(re_check)">**

Comment: Какие ошибки появились в консоли после выноса функции в отдельный файл?

Comment: @vihtor, тогда так код выглядит: :callback => "alert(re_check)", не помогло.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗаварзин, нет ошибок

Comment: Значит нужно смотреть итоговый html который приходит клиенту. Очень сложно определить в чем дело.

Comment: я и не говорил что поможет, но какой был результат?

Comment: @vihtor никакого, что есть callback, что нет